# Boundedness of an inner product and its permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, permutations

Fix $c \in \Bbb{R}$, and suppose $\mathbf{P}_n$ is a [permutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). Must there exist some $\tilde{c}$ such that
$$\mathbf x^\top\mathbf y =c \implies \mathbf x^\top\mathbf P \mathbf y=\tilde{c},$$
whenever $\mathbf x, \mathbf y \in \Bbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You need to clarify the notation. It seems you're trying to denote an infinite sequence $\mathbf{x}_n$, but also have $n$ be some fixed natural number (as defined by $\Bbb{R}^n$, the space containing this sequence).

Comment: Fixed. I removed the sequence wordings from the question.

Comment: The question was still unclear. What was $\tilde{c}$, and how did it relate to $c$? Having sequences implied some kind of quantifiers. Anyway, I've attempted to clarify your question, but I'm not sure this is what you meant. If this was not your intent, please rollback the revisions from the [revisions page](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4429677/revisions).

Comment: Thank you for editing.  This is what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true. If we take $n = 2$, $c = 0$, and $\mathbf{P} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, then $\mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{y} = 0 = c$ when $\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. If such a $\tilde{c}$ existed, it would have to be:
$$\tilde{c} = \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{p} \mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = -3.$$
On the other hand, we could replace $\mathbf{y}$ with $-\mathbf{y}$, i.e. consider $\mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$, and we would still have $\mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{y} = 0 = c$, but
$$\mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{p} \mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 3 \neq \tilde{c}.$$
So, no, this is not in general.